# XCODE 4.2 template Created By

Tags: templates, xcode4.2

I upgraded to XCode 4.2 recently and noticed that in the comment section of all code templates the Created By is not me.  It is actually my daughter (go figure).  I am logged in as me, in build settings i see me as the install owner and i cannot find where i can change that from her to me.

Obviously i am missing something like a hidden setting.  Any thoughts?  She is not even a 'user' on my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting is not in XCode, you need to open up the Address Book app and make sure your contact info is set as you.

You do this by finding your name and choosing Card>Set as My Card after you have highlighted your name.

I had this happen to me too when I setup iCloud for the first time on my Mac after the 4.2 update.

Comment: Wow.  I honestly would have never looked in there.  So strange.